# Magento 2: Error while adding new category or new product

Tags: magento2, new-products

I am facing a error while adding a new product or category from back-end. The error is as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`row_id`, `entity_id`, `created_in`, `updated_in`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Known issue for Magento 2.x, we faced same issue several time for our project on Magento 2.2.x

**Solution worked for me is reindex:** just try below steps, if it doesn't work then let me know output while executing these commands. 
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f

Comment: Also try disabling flat structure for  category and Products

Comment: thanks for the reply but this solution did not work for me. During setup upgrade, I got a error which is as follows.
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW', query was: CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_int FOR EACH ROW

Comment: Try:
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime

once issue is fixed then run this command:
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: if above solution doesn't work then try disabling all third party extensions and check

Comment: When I tried to chnage the indexer mode then I faced the following error: Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW', query was: CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_datetime_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_datetime FOR EACH ROW

Comment: Try disabling third party modules and check. This is a fresh m2 installation or existing? anywhere m2 default db schema modified? If yes then there is a probability of issues because of that.